# How to find out if a Git commit is included in a release?

Tags: git, github, repository, github-for-mac

I am trying to find out if a Git commit is included in a release but seem to be having a hard job via github.com website.

This is the commit that I wish to know if its included in a release

```
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/pull/122/commits
```

Does anyone know the steps for confirming this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `git log --grep=<message>` command. an part of the message will work.
Once there is a match you will see the details of the commit.

Example:

```
git log --grep='pull/122/commits'
```

Executing this line of the given repository does not return results, which means that this pull request is not merged yet.

You can verify the command by this for example to see results:

```
git log --oneline --grep='version'
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to clone the repository for this, right ? I will give it a try.

Comment: yep, you need to clone since github removed the search feature in the commit

Comment: Thanks again for your help

Comment: Sadly, it does not work for commit hashes, but still better than nothing, thanks ;)